# wpf viewmodel with multiple hierarches

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I´m trying to understand the model-view-viewmodel approach. 
Let´s say i have classes called Year, Project, Human. 
Every year contains a List with the projects of the year and every project contains a list with the humans working on the project.

I want to display a overview of all this data. Maybe a TabControl showing the different years, and then lists of associated Projects and their Members inside the TabItems.

Do I now need to create a ModelViewYear refereing to a year and containing a list of associated ModelViewProjects containing a list of associated ModelViewHumans?

Or is this totally wrong and i only need a ModelViewTabitem representing the data?

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: I tried the first version, but struggled with the fact of storing the same infos multiple times (e.g. project contains list of humans and viemodelproject contains list of viewmodelhumans)

Comment: Don't create a viewmodel for every little thing. Have just one for this view (let's say ProjectsViewModel). Every Project type in a collection there will have properties for Year (if you really need a custom type for that) and Human, so you can display them however you want.

Comment: Alright, sounds good!

Answer (score 0):

Your actual requirement is not clear to me.

Are Year, Project, Human data classes? As per my understanding, you want to populate a first list with years, when user clicks on a list item, a new list is displayed and populated with the projects and when user clicks on a particular project, populate a new list with humans data.

Yes this is easily possible to do with an MVVM model. First create a view which contains 3 list views and set the visibility of each listview as per your requirement. Using MVVM bind the itemsource of these list views to the corresponding **ObservableCollection** in the viewmodel of the corresponding view.

You can use these **ObservableCollection**s as your data source and bind the visibility of each list view when an item is selected in the parent list.

Hope you got an understanding of the same.

Comment: yes, they are data classes. I wanted each year to show up as an tabitem which contains project-lists of associated humans.
So you would also create one ModelViewXY class and hold there the different oberservablecollections?

Comment: No you could do everything inside one view model itself. Create a view and a corresponding view model. Inside the view model you can use the same logic as mentioned above for populating a list or table or datagrid as per your requirements and define all the sources there!

Comment: Right, i meant it this way ;)

Comment: Fine. :)
Nice to know that you got the point. Keep coding! :)